# Unable to change value of component programmatically using useState

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the state programmatically while using the `useState` hook.

I defined it this way:

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState({
   text: "Hello StackOverflow!",
   someNumber: 2
});
```

For testing purposes, I created an interval which increases `someNumber` every second.

```
setInterval(() => {
  setData({ ...data, someNumber: data.someNumber + 1 });
}, 1000);
```

When I now mount the component, the text starts flashing very fast with different numbers. I guess the Interval is started multiple times but I don't know why. It's my first project using the new hooks.

A full example of my code can be found [on code sandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usestate-not-working-2z8gk)

And in case the link goes down, here's the component:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default function StateTextFields() {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    text: "Hello StackOverflow!",
    someNumber: 2
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    setData({ ...data, text: "How are you?" });
  }, 1000);

  setInterval(() => {
    setData({ ...data, someNumber: data.someNumber + 1 });
  }, 1000);

  return (
        <TextField
          id="standard-name"
          label="Name"
          value={data.text + " " + data.someNumber}
          margin="normal"
        />
  );
}
```

Comment: Just tested on your sandbox. It works as intended when changing the update function to be as shown in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `setInterval` inside a `useEffect`. This will stop it from creating a new interval every render.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
      setData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, someNumber: prevState.someNumber + 1 }));
    }, 1000);
  setTimeout(...)
},[])
```

This will make it so that these functions only run one time when the component mounts.

Unconditionally calling a function that modifies state inside a functional component is like doing the same in the `render` of a class component. It will modify state, which causes a re-render, which will modify state, and so on infinitely.

You need to use the `prevState` callback to update. This is because `useEffect` is not listening to changes made to `data` like `useEffect(() => {}, [data])` making `data` go stale. But we also don't want to change it to listen to changes, because that would cause your interval to be created infinitely again. So we use `prevState` which always uses the most recent copy of state.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-usestate-not-working-ejd0y

Comment: Great! I updated my answer with the explanation of why we have to do it that way here.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `setTimeout` and `setInterval` on each component render call.

Answer (score 0):

Your Timeouts/Intervals will get fired on every re-render. You have to put it in a `useEffect` which replaced lifecycle hooks like `componentDidMount()`.

Example:

```
useEffect(()=>{

    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setData({ ...data, someNumber: data.someNumber + 1 })
    }, 1000);

    return ()=>{myInterval.clearInterval()} //cleanup

}, []) //The empty array means "only do this once, after the first render"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here.

1. You are setting multiple timeouts/intervals that deal with the same data. They are updating the same values over different periods of time because of the asynchronicity. For example: 
    The `timeout` changes `data` at almost the same time as the `interval`. Which results in the timeout calculating `2 + 1`, meanwhile the interval thinks `data.someNumber` is still `2` instead of `3`.
2. When not using hooks like `React.useEffect` react will recreate the methods each time it rerenders the component, a.k.a. every time state changes, a.k.a. every  time `data` changes.

As [BrianThompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9381601/brian-thompson) pointed out the following solution fixes these problems. I added some comments to explain why.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(() => {
      // using prevState is essential here because it negates the need for 'data' as
      // that would force you to recreate the hook every time 'data' changes
      setData(prevState => ({ ...prevState, someNumber: prevState.someNumber + 1 }));
    }, 1000);
  setTimeout(...)
},[])
```